# PostgreSQL Insert error on a not null Value

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm getting a weird error when trying to execute an insert query on a PostgreSQL database. I'm executing the following query:

```
insert into "shopping_carts" 
(
"application_version", "charges", "device_id", "device_type", "id", "new_client",
"os_version", "platform_name", "resolution", "shopping_cart_date",
"shopping_cart_date_day", "shopping_cart_date_day_of_week",
"shopping_cart_date_day_of_year", "shopping_cart_date_hour",
"shopping_cart_date_minute", "shopping_cart_date_month",
"shopping_cart_date_numeric", "shopping_cart_date_quarter", 
"shopping_cart_date_quarter_name", "shopping_cart_date_second", 
"shopping_cart_date_week_of_year", "shopping_cart_date_year", "status", 
"store_id", "store_name", "tip", "total_after_discounts", "total_discount", 
"total_items", "user_gender", "user_id", "whim_has_photo", "whim_what", 
"whim_where"
) 
values 
(
2.0, 0.0, '105755B41135E2A6F5C09089EE776BA179A4DD290E27B6DC11AFC94534572BD7', 
'smartphone', 'QWFISFJ23434', true, 'Ubuntu 15.10', 'ios', '1920x1080', 
'2016-06-20 18:42:15', 20, 1, 171, 18, 42, 6, 1466448135, 2, 'Second Quarter', 
15, 25, 2016, 'PROGRESS', 15, 'BOG F. Centro Andino', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 32, 
TRUE, 'Lechona', 'Lechoneria de la esquina'
)
```

The error is:

```
Kernel error: ERROR:  null value in column "tip" violates not-null constraint

DETAIL:  Failing row contains (QWFISFJ23434, 0, 0, 0, PROGRESS, null, null, 0, 15, BOG F. Centro Andino, null, null, null, 32, M, Ubuntu 15.10, 1920x1080, 2.0, ios, 105755B41135E2A6F5C09089EE776BA179A4DD290E27B6DC11AFC94534572BD7, smartphone, 2016-06-20 18:42:15, 1466448135, 2016, 6, 20, 2, Second Quarter, 171, 1, 25, 18, 42, 15, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, t, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

I'm clearly sending a value for the "tip" column, so I don't understand why i'm getting this error.

Also, there is some additional information that maybe useful:

1. In the error detail, there is a wierd "t".
2. The shopping_carts table has more column but they are all nullable.
3. In the DB exists 3 tables wich inherit from the shopping_carts table, and have insert rules in the shopping_carts table.
4. I'm using laravel migrations to create the DB

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is this happening when you're seeding the database, or through normal use? What is the exact code you're using to insert the row?

Comment: Also, can you tell us the full definition of that table?

Comment: That `'t'` is another way of representing `true`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I had an insert rule on the shopping_cart child tables. The problem was that I added the "tip" column after the rules where defined.

I had to execute the rules queries again to update them. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the model did not have the value as a fillable.
This may happen from a [mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment) operation.
Just add it like so in the model (in your case 'shopping_cart'):

    `/**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'column0', 'column1', 'add the problematic one here'
    ];`